# Solving given log inequality for another bound of x

Tags: inequality, logarithms, lambert-w

Here's a log inequality I found from Sedgewicks Algorithms in C :
$$ (lnx)^2 < 2\sqrt x $$
Its obviously need to be solved using Lambert W function.. So I proceeded as : 
Taking natural logarithm
$$
2 ln(lnx) < ln2 + \frac 1 2 lnx $$ Allowed since its monotonically increasing, 
Lets suppose : $$ lnx = m $$ for simplicity.And dividing by 2
$$ ln(m) < \frac {ln2} 2 + \frac m 4$$
Taking exponentiation, 
$$ m < \sqrt 2. e^{m/4} $$
$$ m e^ {\frac {-m} 4} < \sqrt 2 $$
$$ \frac {-m} 4 e^ {\frac {-m} 4} > \frac {-\sqrt 2} 4 $$
Using Lambert W Function (+ve branch) on both sides, 
$$ \frac {-m} 4 > W(\frac {-1} {2\sqrt 2}) $$
$$ m < -4 W(\frac {-1} {2\sqrt 2})$$
And,
$$ x < e^{-4W( \frac {-1} {2\sqrt 2} ) } $$
Similarly, taking -ve branch we will get, 
$$ x > e^{-4 W_{-1}(\frac {-1} {2\sqrt 2})}$$
Pluging the approximate value we get, from above
$$ x < 19.6077 $$$$
x > 187.867 $$
Its not complete solution and I'm still missing lower bound of x for which :
$$ y < x < 19.6077 $$
How can y be found ? Is there any way to extract it from above process?

Answer (score 0):

There are three positive real solutions of $\ln(x)^2 = 2 \sqrt{x}$: in increasing numerical order they are

$$ 64 W(\sqrt{2}/4)^4, 64 W(-\sqrt{2}/4)^4, 64 W_{-1}(-\sqrt{2}/4)^4 $$
where $W$ is the principal branch of Lambert W and $W_{-1}$ the "$-1$" branch.

Your inequality is true for $64 W(\sqrt{2}/4)^4 < x < 64 W(-\sqrt{2}/4)^4$ and 
$x > 64 W_{-1}(-\sqrt{2}/4)^4$

Comment: Thats fine but this doesn't help much.  Final answer with process rather than direct one would've helped much...